# Line Winform Control on Visual Studio Options

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

The objective is to imitate an options page on visual studio.
The options page is Tools->Options->TextEditor->C++->General (say).

But I cannot get what control is the 'Line' against section headings. Check in the screenshot for the one highlighted by an arrow.

[image: Visual Studio Options Page]

I have tried the LineShape, Panel etc, but none look as such.

What control is that?
Or how do I imitate it if we do not have such a predefined control?

Comment: Looks like some sought of `GroupBox`.

Comment: Use SysInternals' ZoomIt to get a closer look.  It is just 2 lines, drawn with Graphics.DrawLine().  A groupbox is a huge waste.

Comment: It looks like a LineShape with some color & depth properties, but I can't figure out which ones. It doesn't look like 2 lines to me though.
I do agree, groupbox is not the best way to do this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it either by using a LineShape or a GroupBox

See the image here below for an example (and instructions to make it look like the one you need)

[image]

Comment: I did something similar to what you have done. I am using a Panel with height 1. Not the most ideal solution, but looks almost what I need it to be. Thanks, I am selecting your's as the answer as it's the closest.

Probably someday we can find the best answer though.

Answer (score -1):

It will display the line number of code line. So you can easy track if your code error at some line

Comment: the screenshot we are looking at is a default visual studio options page (the code of which I do not have). And there are no errors in my code, just that I haven't found a control which would look similar to that line. Thanks for your comment.